# border-box: extra characters between elements causes wrap

Tags: html, css

Here is an odd one:

```
<div class='menu-side'>
  <div>
    <div class='name'>
      Name
    </div>
    <div class='item'>
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Extra spaces and CRLFs between name and item elements causes them to wrap even with `box-sizing: border-box` defined

I would like to keep the format of my source code the way it is, without removing extra spaces, and without adding `white-space: nowrap` because that's what `box-sizing: border-box` is implemented for.

https://jsfiddle.net/zm7u5ayj/

(to recreate: remove all characters between elements to become: `</div><div class='item'>`)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Edit: Dirty tricks provided in this question [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements?rq=1) are not comforting solutions for me.**

Comment: What browsers do you need to support? Does the solutions described in this thread not help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements?rq=1? Your problem is not due to `border-box`, it is due to `display: inline-block`.

Comment: There are no solutions provided in this post, only dirty tricks with resetting `font-size` and adding comments. But I guess I'll stick with adding `<!-- -->` for now.

Comment: Those are your only *solutions*. There are none other than those covered in that thread.

Comment: I guess we'll just wait for `white-space-collapsing:discard` or `text-space-collapsing:discard` to be implemented in CSS3

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at a strange and long-running bug with the `margin` of `inline-block` elements that gets undone when a few different things happen. One of those things is formatting the ending and opening tags of the elements right next to eachother and another is giving the elements a `float`, which is probably the sanest way to rectify the issue in your case.

```
.name, .item {
  float: left; // right or left, depending on what you're trying to accomplish
}
```